# How to capture current model name on button click in OpenERP?

Tags: odoo

I am working on OpenERP 8 and I have written a method for a button click.
In that method I need to capture the current model name and assign it to a variable.
Please tell me how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method just call `self._name` to get the model name.